# How to use friend class c++

Tags: c++

I have a rectangle class with a friend point class. I am using cartesian coordinates, so I will have four points in the rectangle class. The points are defined in the point class. When defining the rectangle constructor in the source file, I get the error(marked in comment):

> Rectangle has no member Rectangle

**header:**

```
using namespace std;

class Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle(Point, Point, Point, Point);
    friend class Point;
    ~Rectangle();
private:
    Point a;
    Point b;
    Point c;
    Point d;
};

class Point
{
public:
    Point(int, int);
private:
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

**source:**

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(Point v1, Point v2, Point v3, Point v4)    //error here
{

}

Point::Point(int value1, int value2)
{
    if (x <= 20 && y <= 20){
        x = value1;
        y = value2;
    }
    else{
        throw invalid_argument("");
    }
}
```

Comment: **1st:** What's the reasoning you need `Point` to be `friend` of `Rectangle`? I can't think of any good one. 2nd: To fix your errors, forward declare `class Point;` before declaration of `class Rectangle`.

Comment: You should mention the error you are getting.

Comment: Avoid `friend`- It is more trouble that it is worth.

Comment: @juanchopanza He/she actually did mention it. Just _translated_ from that the compiler is saying ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ah yes, good catch. The fwd declaration is needed for the constructor declaration.

Comment: learning friend in class and trying to learn how to use it

Comment: If you worked at my company, and you put `using namespace std` in a header file, then I would fire you immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the words of inspiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the asterisks in your constructor declaration.

Either forward declare Point, or declare Point before Rectangle.

You also really shouldn't use "using namespace" inside of a header file.

Comment: oops that was supposed to be bold

Answer (score 0):

You're getting compiler errors in your `Rectangle` constructor because `Point` was used un-declared in the header file, you need to either define the `Point` class before or just forward-declare it:

`class Point;`

`friend class` or `friend` in general is meant to make stuff access the class private members, e.g. if you want a global function to access class private members, you would do:

```
class klass {
private:
   int v;
   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const klass& k);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const klass& k)
{
   os << k.v;
   return os;
}
```

So from what you want to do, you would need that `friend class` in the `Point` class not in `Rectangle`