# How to access variables in friend class

Tags: c++

I have a Rectangle class with a friend Point class. I am using cartesian coordinates, so I have four points in the rectangle class. The points are defined in the point class. If the data is initialized like this:

```
int main()
{
    Point w(1.0, 1.0);
    Point x(5.0, 1.0);
    Point y(5.0, 3.0);
    Point z(1.0, 3.0);

    Rectangle r1(x, y, z, w);
}
```

How can I print all of the Points from r1? Also, It is required that I use 4 points for a rectangle and that I use the friend class.

**header:**

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point();
    Point(int, int);
    void printPoint(Rectangle& pt, Point a);
private:
    int x;
    int y;
};

class Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle(Point, Point, Point, Point);
    friend void Point::printPoint(Rectangle& pt, Point a);
    ~Rectangle();
private:
    Point a;
    Point b;
    Point c;
    Point d;
};
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is wrong?

Comment: Two points define a (rectilinear) rectangle, not four…

Comment: Just to make things interesting: a) you don't need four points to define a rectangle, just two (top left & bottom right) b) Point::PrintPoint(does not need any parameters surely - its called to get a point to print itself, c) the friend stuff is not needed

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the [same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890570/how-to-use-friend-class-c), just vice versa now. @reezolv Go back to the comments there now, and consder what these could mean!

Comment: If you intend to use `Point` class with a triangle or octagon, you will need to modify `Point` to add print statements for triangle and octagon.  Bad design.

Answer (score 3):

At the very least, you need to forward declare `Rectangle` before the `Point` class definition. This is because the declaration is needed for the `void printPoint(Rectangle& pt, Point a);` member function.

```
class Rectangle; // fwd declaration

class Point
{
public:
  // as before
```

Other than that it is hard to say, because you give no hints as to what problems you are encountering. It isn't even clear why you need friendship and how you intend to use it.

Comment: This is an assignment for class. We covered friend functions, but not friend classes. All I'm trying to do is print the points from r1.

Answer (score 0):

To print the *vertices* of a rectangle, both `Rectangle` and `Point` need to have print methods.
*Note that the Rectangle prints Points; Points do not print Rectangles.*

```
class Point
{
  public:
    void print(std::ostream& out)
    {
      out << "(' << x << ", " << y << ")";
    }
};

class Rectangle
{
  public:
    void print(std::ostream& out)
    {
      a.print(out); out << "\n";
      b.print(out); out << "\n";
      c.print(out); out << "\n";
      d.print(out); out << "\n";
    }
};
```

I suggest you overload `operator << (std::ostream&)` to make printing of the rectangle and vertices easier.  **Research** the web for "c++ overload operator ostream" to give you some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you're trying to do..
I assume you want to print the points using the rectangle object.

But I found you can't declare a function is friend inside a class before the definition of the class of the friend function first ..

```
class Rectangle;
class Point
{
..
private:
    int x, y;
friend void Rectangle::PrintRectangle(); // doesn't work
```

I think you want to redesign your class..

```
class Rectangle;

class Point
{
public:
    Point();
    Point(int, int);
    void printPoint(); // take out the rectangle parameter here.. and also the point.. use reference to the object (this->)
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    friend Class Rectangle; // declare friend class
};
```

Then in Rectangle class you define the PrintRectangle();

```
class Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle(Point, Point, Point, Point);
    void PrintRectangle(); //
    ~Rectangle();
private:
    Point a;
    Point b;
    Point c;
    Point d;
};
```

in printrectangle you can access the private data of Point object..

```
void Rectangle::PrintRectangle()
{
    int x;
    x = this->a.x;
}
```